# text box not showing for author and comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code in show.html.erb
when i load application it wont show text box for author and comment. not sure whats wrong.

I tried to change it to

```
form_for @book do |f|
```

But then i get error undefined method author

```
<h3>Post Your Comment</h3>
<% form_for([@book, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :author %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :author %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :text, 'Comment' %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_area :text %></p>

  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem in your syntax

```
<% form_for([@book, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for([@book, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
```